# STM32 ADC Reading Instability

Tags: c, stm32, freertos, adc, hal

I am reading 5 ADC channels in polling mode. For each channel I get 10 samples and calculate the average.
Looking for the samples array, it is visible some instability. First readings have higher values and they decrease until the last sample. This behavior is very repetitive.
See the output array (ui32_*Raw*Temp):

First read 1855

Last read 1850

**Original output values**

```
ui32_RawTemp[0]: 1855
ui32_RawTemp[1]: 1855
ui32_RawTemp[2]: 1854
ui32_RawTemp[3]: 1852
ui32_RawTemp[4]: 1852
ui32_RawTemp[5]: 1852
ui32_RawTemp[6]: 1851
ui32_RawTemp[7]: 1851
ui32_RawTemp[8]: 1850
ui32_RawTemp[9]: 1850
```

For debug, I replaced the sensors connected to my ADC channels by fixed resistors, in order to get fixed reading values.

ADC Self calibration is performed before the first channel read. Every 30s the Calibration and 5 reads are repeated.

Here is the original code snippet (for one channel). To make it easier to understand I removed the ADC HAL Error handling.

```
AVG_NUMBER 10
```

```
    sConfig.Rank = 1;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_247CYCLES_5;
    sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
    sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
    sConfig.Offset = 0;

    // reading TEMP1_ADC on channel 5
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_5;

    ADC_HAL_ErrCode = HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig);
    if(ADC_HAL_ErrCode != HAL_OK) {
    ......
    }

    ui32_Temp = 0;
    for(ui8_AVGCounter=0; ui8_AVGCounter < AVG_NUMBER; ui8_AVGCounter++) {
        HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
        HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 10);
        ui16_RawTemp[ui8_AVGCounter] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);  // Read ADC register
        ui32_Temp = ui32_Temp + (uint32_t)ui16_RawTemp[ui8_AVGCounter]; // Sum all read values

        ui16_avgADC[0] = (uint16_t)(ui32_Temp / AVG_NUMBER);    // Calculate the average

        HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
    }
```

After some investigation, I added a delay in my loop and the result is much better. Readings are very stable now.
But, 1ms delay is a lot!

Here is the adapted code snippet, with better results:

```
    // reading TEMP1_ADC on channel 5
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_5;
    sConfig.Rank = 1;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_247CYCLES_5;
    sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
    sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
    sConfig.Offset = 0;

    ADC_HAL_ErrCode = HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig);
    if(ADC_HAL_ErrCode != HAL_OK) {
    .....
    }

    ui32_Temp = 0;
    for(ui8_AVGCounter=0; ui8_AVGCounter < AVG_NUMBER; ui8_AVGCounter++) {
        HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
        HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 10);
        ui32_RawTemp[ui8_AVGCounter] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);    // Read ADC register
        HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);

        ui32_Temp = ui32_Temp + ui32_RawTemp[ui8_AVGCounter];   // Sum all read values

        vTaskDelay(1);
    }
    ui16_avgADC[0] = (uint16_t)((ui32_Temp + (0.5 * AVG_NUMBER)) / AVG_NUMBER); //Round number and Calculate the average
```

See the new output array:

**New output values:**

```
ui32_RawTemp[0]: 1855
ui32_RawTemp[1]: 1855
ui32_RawTemp[2]: 1855
ui32_RawTemp[3]: 1855
ui32_RawTemp[4]: 1855
ui32_RawTemp[5]: 1855
ui32_RawTemp[6]: 1855
ui32_RawTemp[7]: 1855
ui32_RawTemp[8]: 1856
ui32_RawTemp[9]: 1855
```

Questions are:

- Any explanation for this behavior?
- Is something wrong in my code?
- I noticed the first read is the most instable. Should I do something before the first ADC conversion?

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly but 5 / 1855 is ~ only 0.27% error. Isn't it good enough?

Comment: why don't you start the ADC before the loop and stop if after? In my opinion the delay is not doing anything as it outside your ADC acquisition.

Comment: There are all sorts of missing details from this question. Does the ADC require "settle time"? Are your connexions correct? And, most important: Don't posts textual data as images.

Comment: @JardelLucca - Yes, it might be good enough. But, as my input is stable, I just want to understand why the repetitive oscillation, and, mainly if I am doing something wrong in my code.

Comment: @AnthonyB. Stopping after the loop is possible, I tested, but makes no difference in this oscillation. Starting before I don´t think is possible, because I need to start a new conversion every time. Unless I change the ADC configuration to Continues Conversion... But I do not think this is the answer for the oscillation (or?).

Comment: @AdrianMole, first of all, sorry for the images. I thought that could be easier to visualize. The hardware connection and power supply are following the datasheet recommendations. I am not sure about the "settle time" requirement. This could be one reason... Any info about it on the documentation?

Comment: ST have several application notes about the ADC and improving accuracy with oversampling etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is an obvious sign thet your ADC input circuit has too large impedance and the internal ADC capacitance is not loaded fast enough.

If you want to use shorter sampling times you need to lower it by changing the input circuit - for example by adding an operating amplifier (as a voltage repeater)
.

Comment: My input circuit is a simple RC --> 39k series resistor and 10nF ceramic capacitor to ground, placed close to the ADC pin. I believe the 10nF should be enough to charge the very small internal capacitor, in the range of pF. I can have further investigation in this input signal.

Comment: 39k is far too much.

Comment: and RC acts as filter

Comment: I removed the 1ms delay between the readings and tested with a smaller resistor, from 39k to 22k and the stability has improved!

Comment: @IGtti Datasheet says < 10k

Comment: My external system power supply is 24V. In the worst case, if a short circuit to the analog input happens, this series resistor would limit the current injected in the uController pin. (24V - 3V3) / 10k = 2mA It is still inside the maximum allowed of 5mA. But for safety I prefer to keep the resistor a bit higher, like 22k --> the injected current would be lower than 1mA.

Comment: @IGtti use OAmp as voltage followeer - it is always the safest and best option